# Not sure on how to define a function and call it in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

check out my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ybarpz3x/10/), it is for making the `navbar` responsive, it is just something I hacked together cause I can't think of a better way to make the brand and nav text-align on the middle and have their sizes change responsively.

https://jsfiddle.net/ybarpz3x/10/

I bassically have this inside a document ready function,

```
function changeSize() {
    var navHeight = $("navmenu").outerHeight(true);
    var fromTop = $('this').scrollTop()+navHeight; 

    $("nav div a").css({"height" : navHeight + "px","line-height" : navHeight + "px"});

    if (fromTop > navHeight) {
        $("nav li").addClass("top-menu-collapsed");
    }
    else if (fromTop <= navHeight) {
        $("nav li").removeClass("top-menu-collapsed");
    }
}; 

changeSize();
```

Then there's a window.scroll inside that which just runs `changeSize()` on scroll. So `changeSize()` is running on load and then on scrolls.

But I don't think I did it right...?

If anyone can tell quite easily. Please let me know :)

fyi, on jsfiddle the preview window is small and I haven't made a `col-sm` for the nav yet, thanks.

Comment: why not use css media-query ?

Comment: the resizing is for scrolling, ie height of the nav, not for the width or whatever.

Comment: Running you code shows various errors in the console, you first should fixed them. Beside that your `$('this')`  is wrong, because is the string `'this'` and therefor will search for an element with the tag name `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u want a full-width centered navbar on resulution < 800px then use media-query to do it :) Here is your edited media-query:

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #options #big-list ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    columns: 3;
    -webkit-columns: 3;
    -moz-columns: 3;
    padding: 0; } 

    .myleisure a {
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      padding-left: 0;
    }

    #thatnav li {
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
    }
}
```

and here is fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/s2hg14Lq/

Comment: I'm asking how can I change the height of the navbar on scroll!! :) I have used this function to succesfully do it, but I never defined the function, I just ran its code inside the onscroll function. So now I want to just define it as a function and then just be able to run the function instead of copy pasting the code, look at what the function does, it changes the state of the navbar on scroll lower than it's own height, so it's collapsing vertically. It's not to do with screen size

Comment: Ohh okay! first of all you can't use jquery 3.0 with this bootstrap, but I don't know why :) And declare it in your HTML document before bootstrap files. 

And your function is working but it has little error :)

here is working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uq1q5vsg/
You need to check scrollTop(), do not call it on "this" but on window, and i think it's all :)

Comment: oh thank you, wait so none of the jquery stuff is working with it? Do you know what version I can use up to. And also, would you have any idea why this bit doesn't work $("nav div a").css({"height" : navHeight + "px","line-height" : navHeight + "px"}); it isn't adding that styling at all... Thanks a lot my friend :)

Comment: Yea, you need use bigger than 1.9.2 but lower than 3.0.0. jQuery 2.2.4 should be okay, I was testing your code with 2.1.0 and it was working very well :)

First, you need change your navHeight variable becouse you forget about "#" in your jquery element, it should be:

`var navHeight = $("#navmenu").outerHeight(true);`

Then, you are using wrong element, you don't have  `$("nav div a")`, just look at your HTML code. It should be: `$("nav li a").css({"height" : navHeight + "px","line-height" : navHeight + "px"});` Now it's working, but I don't think so it's effect which you wished :))

Comment: no it is meant to be nav div a ;) It's for the branding positioning, thank you so much :)